# Slew Rate Filter With Different Smoothing Factors in Each Direction

Tags: lowpass-filter, smoothing

I'm smoothing the output of an ADC with a simple first order low pass filter.  Of course the smoothing rate is the same whether the signal is rising or falling.

Preferably the smoothing rate needs to be different when the signal is rising vs when it is falling.  Can anyone refer me to an filter/algorithm that would allow this?

For example if the input signal drops fast the filter output would be smoothed a small amount and drop fast.  When the signal rises (even if it's fast) the output of the filter should rise slowly.

Comment: Could you explain why you are smoothing the output of an analog to digital converter. Slew rate is an analog amplifier specification. Your question seems ambiguous to me

Comment: I'm calling it slew rate but maybe that's not the right term.  What I have now is a simple low pass IIR filter with a constant alpha.  The closer alpha is to zero the slower the output signal follows the input (i.e. more smoothed).  The effect I need would be as if the filter has a different alpha when the input signal is increasing vs when it is decreasing.  i.e.  The output should more closely follow the input when the input is decreasing vs when the input is increasing.  Does this make sense?  Is it feasible?

Comment: Sorry I now realize what I asked is not going to feasible as stated.  The requirement is more subtle.  I'll reformulate the problem and repost it.